# Limiting the effects of a stylesheet to the parent widget?

Tags: css, qt, stylesheet

I am setting the background color of a `QWidget` subclass. When I do this using a stylesheet, the styles of the other components in the `QWidget` change (eg, the color of a PushButton, and its look changes).

How do I make sure only the background color of the container widget changes and the rest of the child components remain unchanged?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

One way is to specify an ID selector. Make sure to set the `objectName` of your container widget (with `setObjectName()`) and use that name in the CSS selector. Assuming a widget named `MyContainer`, you would use something like this:

```
QWidget#MyContainer {...}
```

Answer (score -1):

Try !imporant qualifier on child els background color property.

Comment: Qt does not support this qualifier